# Multiple expression in grep

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to find rows that

1. start with 'partition' (a whitespace before that word is ok).
2. the line that came after will contain only ')' (whitespace is allowed).

I manage to get so far:

```
grep -B1 ')' file.log | grep 'partition'
```

I believe what i'm missing is how to add another expression in the first grep command. that way i can add 'not equal to "("'

file.log

```
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0007"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000221"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0008"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000231"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0009"'),
   partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001831"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0010"')
 )
/

 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0007"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000221"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0008"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000231"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0009"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001832"
 )
/


 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0007"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000221"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0008"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000231"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0009"'),
  partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001833"
)
/

 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0007"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000221"
 parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0008"'),
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000000231"
  parameters ('storage "IDXD_ITEM_LOAN_S0009"'),
   partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001834"
     )
/
```

Desired output

```
partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001832"
partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001833"
partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001834"
```

Comment: I dont ask in order. that's why I believe it can be accomplish with only grep. I tried `-v`, got me weird results.

Comment: Anyway, from your exaple file you get what you need just with

`cat file.txt | grep "partition"`

Ahn sorry, now i understand!

Comment: no, it returns all the `partition` rows

Comment: Solve it by searching for something else. Now I search for `/` instead of `)` and in grep I use `-B2`

Comment: Something like this?

`cat file.txt | grep -B2 "/" | grep "partition"`

Nice! Good work, usefull. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I don't ask in order". You're trying to find lines depending on the line that follows. That's a multi-line match problem, which is why you can't do it with grep.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -PB1 '\s\)|^\)' tst.txt | grep 'partition'
```

if you want to get rid of leading whitespace you can pipe through sed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -P (PCRE)`:

```
grep -P '^ *partition(?=.*?\n *\) *\n)' file.log 
 partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001832"
  partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001833"
   partition "P_ITEM_LOAN_0000001834"
```